# Using a string variable as regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, we append `/g` to an unquoted string to denote a regular expression.

What if I have a string in a variable and want to use it as a regular expression?

Is this possible? If so, can anyone show me some example code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
new RegExp("your regex here", "modifiers");
```

And notice that `/g` is not the delimiter for a regex, it is global modifier. A regex looks like this: `/your regex here/modifiers`. `modifiers` can be a combination of `g`, `i` and `m`. They are all explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 5):

`/g` is a flag denoting global ( match all instances of the regex ), it doesn't denote a regular expression but is simply a flag.

If you want a dynamic regex use `new RegExp`. Usage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: In fact, `/g` consists of a flag *and* the leading slash.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Gabi, you helpmed a lot. However, I had to put the regexp part (the variable part) without quotes to make it work:

```
new RegExp(yourRegExp, "modifiers").
```

I hope this helps someone.