# Convert a string variable to regular expression in java script?

Tags: javascript, regex

so I am trying to search a string for a sub string, and apparently, I must use regular expressions with the .search function, this is the code I have

```
var str = items[i].toLowerCase;
var str2 = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase;

var index = str.search(str2);
```

Obhiously this doesn't work and I get an error, saying str.search is not a function, how would I go about changing these two strings into regular expressions?

thanks

Comment: str and str2 are both pointing to the function `toLowerCase`, is this a typo, or did you forget to actually call them? (`...toLowerCase()`)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
new RegExp("your regex here", "modifiers");
```

Take a look into:
[Using a string variable as regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786996/using-a-string-variable-as-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

add braces to your function calls:

```
var str = items[i].toLowerCase();
var str2 = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();
var index = str.search(str2);
```

otherwise type of "str" is a function, not result of function execution

Answer (score 0):

your problem is forgetting a set of brackets () -- and as such str and str2 get assigned a function rather than the result of calling that function! Simply change the code:

```
var str = items[i].toLowerCase();
var str2 = document.getElementById("input").value.toLowerCase();

var index = str.search(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an expression in a RegExp constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp(str, 'g');
```

will create a regular expression to match the value of `str` in a string, so:

```
var str = 'foo';
var re = new RegExp(str, 'i');
```

is equivalent to the RegExp literal:

```
var re = /foo/i;
```

You can use any expression that evaluates to a valid regular expression, so to match foo at the start of a string:

```
var re = new RegExp('^' + str, 'i');
```

The only niggle is that quoted characters must be double quoted, so to match whitespace at the end of a string:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\s+$');
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var re = /\s+$/;
```