# regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a string variable as regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786996/using-a-string-variable-as-regular-expression)

I have a var that contains all English words. I want to use regular exp in order to filter the words according to specific letter that are stored in a var.

```
 var letter1 = "a";
    var letter2 = "b";
var words= "aardvark aardwolf aaron aback abacus abaft abalone abandon abandoned abandonment abandons abase abased abasement abash abashed abate abated abatement abates abattoir";
```

I tried this in order to find all the words that have the letter "a" and "b", but it is not working:

```
document.writeln(words.match(/letter1 +/ + letter2 +/g));
```

Comment: Your intent is not quite clear. What _exactly_ do you want to get? All the words containing `letter1` and `letter2` at the same time?

Comment: Provide 1. Expected result, 2. Actual Result, 3. Code

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 var abc = ["asdf","asfdf","sdgsdwvc","avdvcccv","acbfd","sdfsd","gvvfvbb","sdfge34"];
 var pattern = /.*[ab].*/i;
 var res;
 for(a in abc)
 {
  res = abc[a].match(pattern);
  if(res!=null || res!=undefined)
 alert(res);
 }
</script>`

Answer (score 3):

this pattern should do it:

```
/\S*[ab]\S*/g
```

and so

```
var pattern = new RegExp('\S*['+letter1+'|'+letter2+']\S*','g');
var matches = words.match(pattern);
document.writeln(matches);
```

Comment: I need to find the whole word not only the two letters

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "acadfb".match(/a.*b|b.*a/)
["acadfb"]
>>> "basdfc".match(/a.*b|b.*a/)
["ba"]
>>> "asdfbasdfcvb".match(/a.*b|b.*a/)
["asdfbasdfcvb"]
>>> "cadsfg".match(/a.*b|b.*a/)


var myStringArray = ["Hello","World","asdfsadf","asdbc","cdjfieab"];
for (var i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++) {
   if(myStringArray[i].match(/a.*b|b.*a/)){
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);
   };
}
```